# When can Overhaul reassemble a living organism?

Tags: my-hero-academia

Supposedly Overhaul can bring back from death to people by reassembling their broken biological parts. But in the animated series he said to the league of villains he owed them an arm of their own people, since he took off Mr Compress's arm, but he never tried to re-assemble his arm when theorically he might be able to do it?

When can Overhaul reassemble a living organism?

Comment: It's possible he could have restored Mr Compress' arm, but chose to not do so as leverage against the League. Or, by that point, the atoms from the arm might have dispersed so much they couldn't be restored into their original form any more since he has to touch things to affect them.

Comment: The other question is: why would he want to? Mr. Compress is not a member of Shie Hassaikai, is not Overhaul's friend and moreover, he's only trying to use the League of Villains. He has nothing to gain by reassembling Mr. Compress' arm. So, why would he want to?

Comment: With regards to your question, there has been no restrictions mentioned in the manga IIRC, as long as his hands remain intact which allows him to use his Quirk, so he can disassemble/reassemble anytime he wants to.

Answer (score 1):

Overhaul can use his quirk whenever his hands touch the specific thing he wants to disassemble or assemble, including living organism.

> In the past, when he recruited Kendo Rappa, a heavily experienced brawler, into the Shie Hassaikai, Kendo proposed that, in order to gain his servitude, Overhaul has to defeat him in battle. But just as Kendo prepared an attack, the Yakuza leader effortlessly **disassembled, then reassembled Kendo**.

This means that he can reassemble any living organism that he touches back to it's former state, although the series didn't point out if there is a time limit for reassembling "living" things giving that organisms die after a short time.

So I am inclined to believe that he can reassemble living organism in the short span of time that they are "alive". For exemple, if Mr Compress's wound would heal then it could not be reassembled anymore.